# Find item between row and column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` that looks like this:

```
type1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 27,21], ['C',21,14]], columns= ['Type', 'A','C'])
```

And I want to find the value between row and column, for instance:

-Value between row:'A' and column:'C', the expected output would be: 21

I tried to use:
`bool_index=type1.loc[i,'A'] and type1.loc[i,'C']`, but it isn't working.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: try:- `type1.loc[1,'A']`....if this is not your answer then please simplify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: your dataframe constructor throws an error. Also please can you add your expected output?

Comment: Yeah exactly so I created a sample df by `type1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 27,21], ['C',21,14]], columns= ['Type', 'A','C'])`

Comment: I corrected the dataframe, and I included also an example

Comment: `type1.set_index('Type').loc['A','C']`

Comment: so simple and yet so right! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer posted by @anky solved my problem: type1.set_index('Type').loc['A','C']